# $AB = BA $ in a group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group , $ A \subset G $ and $ B \subset G $ are subsets of $G$, if $AB = BA$ is it true that $AB$ is a subgroup of $G$ ? Why ?

Comment: Do you assume that $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of $G$?

Comment: no, I've edited

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are not assumed to be subgroups of $G$ themselves, then the answer is trivial. Take $G = \Bbb{Z}$ and let $A = B = \{ 1 \}$. Then, $AB = BA = \{ 2 \}$. But, clearly $AB$ is not a subgroup of $G$.